# Redirecting output to a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

This is my controllers/lead_billing/lead_billings_controller.rb:

In controllers/admin/lead_billings_controller.rb, I have:

```
  def create
    @lead_billing = LeadBilling.new(params[:lead_billing])
    @lead_billing.generate_model_id
    @lead_billing.add_ticket_id_to_model(ticket_id)
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead_billing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ticket, notice: 'Lead billing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @lead_billing, status: :created, location: @lead_billing }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @lead_billing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

What I want to do, is then the lead_billing is saved, to re-direct to the show method of the tickets controller.

When I run it, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `ticket_url' for #<Admin::LeadBillingsController:0x0000000898c990>
```

Routes related to tickets:

```
tickets   GET   /tickets/:id(.:format)   statics#tickets
update_state_admin_ticket   PUT   /admin/tickets/:id/update_state(.:format)   admin/tickets#update_state
toggle_flag_admin_ticket   PUT   /admin/tickets/:id/toggle_flag(.:format)   admin/tickets#toggle_flag
edit_notes_admin_ticket   GET   /admin/tickets/:id/edit_notes(.:format)   admin/tickets#edit_notes
download_work_order_admin_ticket   GET   /admin/tickets/:id/download_work_order(.:format)   admin/tickets#download_work_order
fancybox_show_admin_ticket   GET   /admin/tickets/:id/fancybox_show(.:format)   admin/tickets#fancybox_show
to_step_admin_tickets   GET   /admin/tickets/to_step(.:format)   admin/tickets#to_step
creator_admin_tickets   GET   /admin/tickets/creator(.:format)   admin/tickets#creator
admin_tickets   GET   /admin/tickets(.:format)   admin/tickets#index
POST   /admin/tickets(.:format)   admin/tickets#create
new_admin_ticket   GET   /admin/tickets/new(.:format)   admin/tickets#new
admin_ticket   GET   /admin/tickets/:id(.:format)   admin/tickets#show
PUT   /admin/tickets/:id(.:format)   admin/tickets#update
DELETE   /admin/tickets/:id(.:format)   admin/tickets#destroy
```

Instead of showing me the ticket. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show what routes tells, `rake routes`?

Comment: That's a lot of routes. I will post the tickets related routes. According to the Rails docs, isn't the model supposed to tell rails how to handle the routing? I know that the show ticket method works fine already. I will append the routes to the question.

Comment: You can `grep` for just ticket related routes.

Comment: I added the routes to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route has `admin_ticket`. Try `redirect_to admin_ticket_path(@ticket)`.

Comment: I will try it, but I thought that the Rails docs are explicit on this: as long as @ticket is valid, and I did not get an error code on that, it's smart enough to tell Rails how to route.

Comment: Yes, but your route has `admin` but your `@ticket` class does not have admin in it.

Comment: It worked. I guess this is a side effect of having created @ticket, from the lead_billings controller, even though the lead_billings controller, is an Admin class controller. I wonder if there's a way to force create an Admin class ticket.

Answer (score 0):

haven't done that way, why not declare it this way?

```
redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
```

Comment: I will try it, but the Rails docs say that this is not needed. All you have to do, is redirect to @ticket and it should understand